# Conexion erronea de Android con SQLServer

Tags: java, android, sql-server

Estoy comenzando a programar en Android Studio un pequeño proyecto. Quiero hacer una consulta a la base, en el caso de que la conexion falle me da un mensaje en un Toast:

```
Network error IDException: failed to connect to /ANDRESPC\SQLEXPRESS
(port 1433): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

Donde `/ANDRESPC\SQLEXPRESS` es la instancia de sqlexpress

```
Attempt to invoke interface method
'java.sql.PreparedStatementjava.sql.Conn
ection.prepareStatement(java.lang.String)'
on a null object reference
```

El codigo de la conexion es este:

```
public Connection conexionBD() {
        Connection conexion = null;
        try{
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ANDRESPC\\SQLEXPRESS;databasename=speedex1;user=andres;password=123;");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return conexion;
    }
```

El codigo de la codigo de la consulta es este:

```
public void consultarPaquete() {
        try {
            PreparedStatement pat = conexionBD().prepareStatement("SELECT es.estado, en.fechaLlegada, t.transporte, en.precioTotal FROM estado es, envio en, medioTransporte t WHERE es.estadoId = en.estadoId AND t.transporteId = en.transporteId AND en.envioId = ?");
            pat.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(envio));
            pat.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet rs = pat.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                //asignandole a los atributos de la clase

                estado = rs.getString(1);
                fecha = rs.getString(2);
                transporte = rs.getString(3);
                precio = rs.getDouble(4);
            }
            //cerrando conexion
            pat.close();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Consulta exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Y el codigo para ejecutar esto esta en una clase que se activa en el evento `onClick` de un boton:

```
public void ejecutarConsulta(View view) {

    consultarPaquete();
    System.out.println("El estado es " + estado + "/n" + "La fecha es " + fecha + "/n" + "El tipo de transporte es " + transporte + "/n" + "El precio es " + precio);
}
```

Mi pregunta es 
¿por qué da error? Me equivoqué en la forma de hacer la conexión o de hacer la consulta?

Comment: Es recomendable hacer uso del Logcat para saber donde falla tu proyecto..

Comment: ¿Como hago uso del Logcat?

Comment: Vsita: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html?hl=es-419 para que vayas entendiendo ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

revisa desde que el celular y desde instancias la conexion se pueda resolver al ping ANDRESPC, si no lo resuelve colocar la ip que se pueda ver.

prueba primero  haciendo una conexion de esa forma en sql manager, instancia ANDRESPC, usuario y contraseña, si te conecta revisa que se pueda conectar.

Revisa que el puerto 1433 este recibiendo las conexiones y que este configurado en la clase conexion

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Nestor!, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer 
el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además es **muy importante revisar 
[answer]** que te da brinda información para realizar una buena respuesta. Si deseas editar tu pregunta/respuesta ve a [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/103796/edit) , saludos.

Comment: Vi en un lugar eso que me dices de usar la ip. El unico problema es que no se exactamente que ip utilizar, la de mi computadora en la red?

Comment: la ip debe ser la del equipo, si esta en una lan puede verse, en caso de que no puedas verla,  baja el firewall del equipo y  revisa que luego de la ip  este de esta forma ip:1433, el puerto 1433 es el que utiliza sql para la escucha y en tu clase conexion no la tienes.

Comment: utiliza asi la conexion [ DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ANDRESPC\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=BD", "USUARIO", "CONTRASEÑA");]

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el fallo que estas teniendo es que no estas usando el driver correspondiente. Cuando se hace una conexión desde java es necesario tener el driver de jdbc para poder hacer llamadas a BBDD en caso de android no debes tenerlo.

Lo que no entiendo es el motivo porque usas la BBDD SQLserver ya que si es solo para guardar datos deberias usar la propia de android SQLite y en caso que debas usarla tirar directamente contra BBDD es peligroso mejor montar un webservice que filtre esas llamadas

Comment: Uso SQLServer porque el sistema original de escritorio que estoy desarollando esta en ese gestor. Quiero hacer este pequeño proyecto en android como "plus" del proyecto principal

Answer (score 0):

El error que obtienes, es generado al llamar el método `prepareStatement()` pero la conexión tiene valor null:

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.PreparedStatement
>   java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(java.lang.String)

Es importante revises que problema tienes en la conexión y valides de esta forma cuando la conexión tiene un valor null:

```
public void consultarPaquete() {
        try {
            Connection conn = connectionBD(driver);
            if(conn != null) {
             PreparedStatement pat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT es.estado, en.fechaLlegada, t.transporte, en.precioTotal FROM estado es, envio en, medioTransporte t WHERE es.estadoId = en.estadoId AND t.transporteId = en.transporteId AND en.envioId = ?");
             pat.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(envio));
             pat.executeUpdate();
             ResultSet rs = pat.executeQuery();
             if(rs.next()){
                 //asignandole a los atributos de la clase

                estado = rs.getString(1);
                fecha = rs.getString(2);
                transporte = rs.getString(3);
                precio = rs.getDouble(4);
             }
             //cerrando conexion
             pat.close();

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Consulta exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection to server failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

---

Revisa el método `conexionBD()` , asegura la instancia sea la correcta, podrías necesitar definir el puerto. Revisa las credenciales. Revisa cual es el mensaje en  `e.getMessage()`